# Pythonaddins Message Box encoding problem

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, python-addin, encoding

I've been trying to create a MessageBox with accented characters.  To do so, I used the decode() and encode() functions. The code is part of a Python Toolbox.

`pythonaddins.MessageBox("ééàà".decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252'), "My title", 0)`

And that's the result I get:

[image: MessageBox with wrong characters]

I've also set the default encoding to utf-8 at the beginning of my script:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Strangely, when I try it directly in the ArcGIS Python console, it gives the right result:

[image: Good result]

It seems like running the code from the Python console in ArcGIS doesn't give the same result as running it from a Python tool ...

I've tried lots of things to fix this like:

- Setting the text string in Unicode

`pythonaddins.MessageBox(u'ééàà'.encode('cp1252'), "My title", 0)`

- Using Windows popups

`ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "ééàà", "My title", 0)`

... and it still behaves the same way (works in ArcGIS Python console but not from the toolbox).

Ideas why this is happening?

---

EDIT:
This is an example of tool code that doesn't give the right result:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
import pythonaddins`

`class MsgBoxTest(object):`

```
def __init__(self):
    """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
    .pyt file)."""
    self.label = "MsgBoxTest"
    self.alias = ""

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [MsgBoxTest]
```

`class MsgBoxTest(object):`

```
def __init__(self):
    """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
    self.label = "MsgBoxTest"
    self.description = ""
    self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    params = None
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    message = "ààéé"
    pythonaddins.MessageBox(message.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252'),"Attention",0)
    return
```

Comment: I think we need you to provide a slightly longer code snippet that works up to where you are stuck. I am not sure that mixing Python AddIn functionality with Python Toolbox code is appropriate because the former accesses the ArcMap GUI.

Comment: @PolyGeo The rest of my code isn't really linked with the message box, I don't think it could help. I can tell you that there is a return statement just after the message box line. Also, I can tell you that this code line is located in the Python toolbox. I think that your idea is quite on point however. I'm gonna do some research on this.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about the rest of your code, just a test Python Toolbox with one test tool that potential answerers could copy/paste and open to see what you are describing.

Comment: I think that this might be a bug with pythonaddins.MessageBox, I'm having the same problem and am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I do think it's a bug coming from pythonaddins too! I think the next step would be warning ESRI about this.